# MySQL IF ELSE Conditions

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I need a query to check the table with few conditions and return one result:

```
SELECT 

    IF(id='123' AND user='alex') FOUND -> return false ELSE -> return true
    IF(user='alex') NOT FOUND -> return false

FROM `table`
```

I have no idea on how to build such query in php function, when it call, result `true` or `false` will return

```
function check(id, user)
{
    $q = $mysqli->query("...sql query...");

    if($q->num_rows > 0){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Read this first http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-case-statement/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Forget about PHP code at this stage.**

*Think more high-level.*

First thing you need to do is grab the right data to associate to a variable.

Use [HeidiSQL](https://www.heidisql.com/) (useful, reliable tool, open-source and entirely free to use) for testing the queries within your DB.

```
CASE WHEN (table.id='123' AND table.user='alex') 
       THEN 1
       ELSE 0
END AS alexexists
```

or the simpler:

```
(table.id='123' AND table.user='alex') AS alexexists
```

*This works because TRUE is displayed as 1 in MySQL and FALSE as 0.*

Answer (score 1):

here is also a suggestion 
you can also create a query like

```
Select (case when table.id='123' and table.user='alex' then false
            when table.id!='alex' then false
            else true End ) as  alexexists
from table;
```